# How do I merge two XML variables

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

The output from a scatter-gather is two variables with identically formatted XML files. I now need to merge the two files into one. Experimentation and searching has not turned up any example code in combining two XML files.

Input 1 comes from one reporting process and Input 2 comes from a different report. The format will always be the same except for the "TYPE" parameter. I want to drop the "DATE" line and merge all of the records.

Input 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
  <DATE>2021-03-02T00:00:01.000+00:00</DATE>
  <RECORD>
    <ADDRESS>4006 Viking Drive</ADDRESS>
    <CITY>GLOVERVILLE</CITY>
    <STATE>SC</STATE>
    <ZIP>29828</ZIP>
    <NAME>Mickey</NAME>
    <TYPE>This Type</TYPE>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <ADDRESS>2279 Oak Street</ADDRESS>
    <CITY>ROCKVILLE</CITY>
    <STATE>MD</STATE>
    <ZIP>20851</ZIP>
    <NAME>Donald</NAME>
    <TYPE>This Type</TYPE>
  </RECORD>
</DATA>
```

Input 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
  <DATE>2021-03-02T00:00:01.000+00:00</DATE>
  <RECORD>
    <ADDRESS>2759 Drainer Avenue</ADDRESS>
    <CITY>Tallahassee</CITY>
    <STATE>FL</STATE>
    <ZIP>32301</ZIP>
    <NAME>Goofy</NAME>
    <TYPE>A Different Type</TYPE>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <ADDRESS>3352 Limer Street</ADDRESS>
    <CITY>Atlanta</CITY>
    <STATE>GA</STATE>
    <ZIP>30303</ZIP>
    <NAME>Pluto</NAME>
    <TYPE>A Different Type</TYPE>
  </RECORD>
</DATA>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
  <RECORD>
    <ADDRESS>4006 Viking Drive</ADDRESS>
    <CITY>GLOVERVILLE</CITY>
    <STATE>SC</STATE>
    <ZIP>29828</ZIP>
    <NAME>Mickey</NAME>
    <TYPE>This Type</TYPE>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <ADDRESS>2279 Oak Street</ADDRESS>
    <CITY>ROCKVILLE</CITY>
    <STATE>MD</STATE>
    <ZIP>20851</ZIP>
    <NAME>Donald</NAME>
    <TYPE>This Type</TYPE>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <ADDRESS>2759 Drainer Avenue</ADDRESS>
    <CITY>Tallahassee</CITY>
    <STATE>FL</STATE>
    <ZIP>32301</ZIP>
    <NAME>Goofy</NAME>
    <TYPE>A Different Type</TYPE>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <ADDRESS>3352 Limer Street</ADDRESS>
    <CITY>Atlanta</CITY>
    <STATE>GA</STATE>
    <ZIP>30303</ZIP>
    <NAME>Pluto</NAME>
    <TYPE>A Different Type</TYPE>
  </RECORD>
</DATA>
```

Comment: Please provide examples of inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am taking your inputs as a variable inside DataWeave as you mentioned in your question,
(if **it's not coming in a variable** out from Scatter-Gather then just tweak the DWL code and get inputs from payload directly as payload[0].payload.DATA.*RECORD and payload[1].payload.DATA.*RECORD)

Use the below code just after your scatter-gather, it will remove the "DATE" parameter, and also if the "type" parameter is not coming that also will not make any impact

**Handling NULL also if any variable comes null**

```
%dw 2.0
    output application/xml
    var input1 = read('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <DATA>
    <DATE>2021-03-02T00:00:01.000+00:00</DATE>
    <RECORD>
        <ADDRESS>4006 Viking Drive</ADDRESS>
        <CITY>GLOVERVILLE</CITY>
        <STATE>SC</STATE>
        <ZIP>29828</ZIP>
        <NAME>Mickey</NAME>
        <TYPE>This Type</TYPE>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <ADDRESS>2279 Oak Street</ADDRESS>
        <CITY>ROCKVILLE</CITY>
        <STATE>MD</STATE>
        <ZIP>20851</ZIP>
        <NAME>Donald</NAME>
        <TYPE>This Type</TYPE>
    </RECORD>
    </DATA>','application/xml')

    var input2 = read('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <DATA>
    <DATE>2021-03-02T00:00:01.000+00:00</DATE>
    <RECORD>
        <ADDRESS>2759 Drainer Avenue</ADDRESS>
        <CITY>Tallahassee</CITY>
        <STATE>FL</STATE>
        <ZIP>32301</ZIP>
        <NAME>Goofy</NAME>
        <TYPE>A Different Type</TYPE>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <ADDRESS>3352 Limer Street</ADDRESS>
        <CITY>Atlanta</CITY>
        <STATE>GA</STATE>
        <ZIP>30303</ZIP>
        <NAME>Pluto</NAME>
        <TYPE>A Different Type</TYPE>
    </RECORD>
    </DATA>','application/xml')
    ---
    { 
       DATA : RECORD : (input1.DATA.*RECORD default []) ++ (input2.DATA.*RECORD default [])
    }
```

**output**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<DATA>
  <RECORD>
    <ADDRESS>4006 Viking Drive</ADDRESS>
    <CITY>GLOVERVILLE</CITY>
    <STATE>SC</STATE>
    <ZIP>29828</ZIP>
    <NAME>Mickey</NAME>
    <TYPE>This Type</TYPE>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <ADDRESS>2279 Oak Street</ADDRESS>
    <CITY>ROCKVILLE</CITY>
    <STATE>MD</STATE>
    <ZIP>20851</ZIP>
    <NAME>Donald</NAME>
    <TYPE>This Type</TYPE>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <ADDRESS>2759 Drainer Avenue</ADDRESS>
    <CITY>Tallahassee</CITY>
    <STATE>FL</STATE>
    <ZIP>32301</ZIP>
    <NAME>Goofy</NAME>
    <TYPE>A Different Type</TYPE>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <ADDRESS>3352 Limer Street</ADDRESS>
    <CITY>Atlanta</CITY>
    <STATE>GA</STATE>
    <ZIP>30303</ZIP>
    <NAME>Pluto</NAME>
    <TYPE>A Different Type</TYPE>
  </RECORD>
</DATA>
```

also here I am showing how to read XML in a variable using DWL

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the scatter-gather response consisting of the 2 payloads, you can use something like this:

```
{ DATA: 
    (payload[0].payload.DATA ++ payload[1].payload.DATA) - "DATE"
}
```

As the XML is considered like an object and each tag is an attribute that can be repeated, what I'm doing is join the two DATA object attributes and then removing the DATE attribute. Then, I'm wrapping it inside a new DATA root object.